# Sentiment Analysis - polarity

Tags: nlp, textblob

If Polarity is 0.0 in TextBlob, whether the sentence is purely negative or it means no output.

```py
wiki = TextBlob ("Python is a high-level, general-purpose programming language.")

wiki.sentiment
```

output: Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)

Please explain what the output is actually telling to us?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Neutral (neither positive nor negative)

---

**Explanation:**

If you go through the docs here: https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#sentiment-analysis

And see the example here:

```
testimonial = TextBlob("Textblob is amazingly simple to use. What great fun!")
testimonial.sentiment
```

**Output:**

> Sentiment(polarity=0.39166666666666666,
>   subjectivity=0.4357142857142857)

You can see that the range of polarity varies between -1 and 1 where the positive end denotes positive tone, and negative end denotes negative tone in the sentence. *Hence, a polarity of 0 would be neutral.* It also completely makes sense in your case as one cannot say if your sentence is positive or negative.

Similarly, check out another example from: https://planspace.org/20150607-textblob_sentiment/

```
TextBlob("not great").sentiment
```

**Output:**

> Sentiment(polarity=-0.4, subjectivity=0.75)

Comment: At first, I misunderstood that the range is in between 0 and 1. Now I understood the concept. Thanks.